# Future not being returned from await function as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

The function `signInWithGoogle` calls the `getUser` function to retrieve the user information from the Firestore Database and expects a `User` as the return. Because this is a Firestore API call, the `User` returned by `getUser` is a `Future` and `getUser` is called with an `await`.

In the `getUser` function, the `User` is populated as expected and verified with the `debugPrint("new user schedule 0: " + i[0].toJson());`

However in the `signInWithGoogle` function, the `User` is not received back from the `Future<User>`, as seen in the null reference to `schedule` when performing `debugPrint("user schedule 0: " + u.schedule[0].toJson());`

I have tried setting the return value in multiple ways (`getUser` function), including instantiating a user class separately before setting it's values and returning it.

```dart
Future<User> getUser(_uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot qs = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(_uid)
        .get();
    if (qs.exists) {
      setState(() {
        state.loadingStatus = "Getting User Information";
      });
      return new User(
        schedule: await getRecipes(
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(_uid)
                .collection('schedule')
        ).then((i) {
          debugPrint("get schedule");
          debugPrint("new user schedule 0: " + i[0].toJson());
        }).catchError((error) {
          debugPrint('Error: $error');
        }),
        favorites: await getRecipes(
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(_uid)
                .collection('favorites')
        ).then((i) {debugPrint("get favorites");}).catchError((error) {
          debugPrint('Error: $error');
        }),
        subscription: await getSubscription(_uid).then((i) {debugPrint("get subscription");}),
        pantry: await getIngredientsList(
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(_uid)
                .collection('pantry')
        ).then((i) {debugPrint("get pantry");}).catchError((error) {
          debugPrint('Error: $error');
        }),
        shopping: await getIngredientsList(
            Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(_uid)
                .collection('shopping')
        ).then((i) {debugPrint("get shopping list");}).catchError((error) {
          debugPrint('Error: $error');
        }),
        preferences: await getPreferences(_uid).then((i) {debugPrint("get preferences");}),
      );
    }else {
      setState(() {
        state.loadingStatus = "Creating new User Information";
      });
      return User.newUser();
    }
  }

  Future<Null> signInWithGoogle() async {
    setState(() {
      state.loadingStatus = "Signing in with Google";
    });
    if (googleAccount == null) {
      // Start the sign-in process:
      googleAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await signIntoFirebase(googleAccount);
    User user = await getUser(firebaseUser.uid);
    debugPrint("user schedule 0: " + user.schedule[0].toJson());
    setState(() {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.loadingStatus = "";
      state.user = firebaseUser;
      state.userInfo = user;
    });
  }
```

```
I/flutter (17962): new user schedule 0: {Proper data is printed here...
I/flutter (17962): get favorites
I/flutter (17962): get subscription
I/flutter (17962): get pantry
I/flutter (17962): get shopping list
I/flutter (17962): get preferences
E/flutter (17962): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (17962): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17962): Tried calling: [](0)
```

I expect to not receive a null reference error when printing the `schedule[0]` from `signInWithGoogle` when the same call to print `schedule[0]` works in the  `getUser` function.

This is probably something stupid simple I am missing, but I cannot figure out what is happening after looking through my code for the past 3 hours.

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Comment: You say you did not receive a `User`, but the error indicates that  you did and that the `schedule` getter returns null.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is around here:

```
schedule: await getRecipes(
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .document(_uid)
      .collection('schedule')
  ).then((i) {
    debugPrint("get schedule");
    debugPrint("new user schedule 0: " + i[0].toJson());

    // this is a problem, there is no return!

  }).catchError((error) {
    debugPrint('Error: $error');
  }),
```

This passes a `null` to the `schedule:` argument, which was not your intention. When you `await someFuture.then(something)` you get out the *return value* from `something`, which is `null` in this case, not the resolved value of `someFuture`.

This is one of the reasons we [recommend not to mix `async/await` with `.then`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-asyncawait-over-using-raw-futures)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is causing the issue but you're mixing Futures and async/awaits. You really only need one. This line:

```
 User user = await getUser(firebaseUser.uid).then((u) {debugPrint("user schedule 0: " + u.schedule[0].toJson());});
```

...could be seen a little simpler as:

```
User user = await getUser(firebaseUser.uid);

print(user.schedule[0].toJson());
```

The async/await *is* returning a future. Placing a .then() callback with an async/await statement isn't necessary.

Comment: That was part of me trying to debug this issue and make sure that the debugPrint was  definitely happening after the user was returned from the Future through the Async call.

Either way, I still receive the null reference error from the print statement in the signInWithGoogle function.